# Bit-Flag for decimal 8 in File Attribute

Tags: windows, file, bitflags

[This site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/gg258117(v=vs.85).aspx) gives a overview of file-flags currently in use. I miss the value 8 in the table.

```
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE 32 (0x20)
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED 2048 (0x800)
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE 64 (0x40)
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY 16 (0x10)
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED 16384 (0x4000)
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN 2 (0x2)
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_INTEGRITY_STREAM 32768 (0x8000)
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL 128 (0x80)
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED 8192 (0x2000)
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NO_SCRUB_DATA 131072 (0x20000)
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE 4096 (0x1000)
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY 1 (0x1)
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_DATA_ACCESS 4194304 (0x400000)
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_OPEN 262144 (0x40000)
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT 1024 (0x400)
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SPARSE_FILE 512 (0x200)
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM 4 (0x4)
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY 256 (0x100)
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_VIRTUAL 65536 (0x10000)
```

Any idea whats the meaning of the flag having the value `8`? It is missing in other languages too.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow should be self-contained. Don't hide vital information behind links to off-site resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If something is not listed then it is undocumented, reserved, or has never been used.

If you google `ATTR_VOLUME` you will see that this is the [volume label directory entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system#Directory_entry) on FAT file systems.